# Some SSH commands do nothing?

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod, ssh

I've been exploring SSH on my iPod and have noticed that some commands seem to just leave the console hanging or do nothing all together. Some examples are 'simulatecrash' or when I try to launch an app. If anybody has any ideas on why these do nothing, I'd appreciate your input. Thanks in advance.

Also, if it matters, I have a 32GB iPod Touch 4g running iOS 4.3.3 and it is jailbroken.

Answer (score 1):

I found a [thread](http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=205101) about the `simulatecrash` command. It says you need to use `simulatecrash -h` to make it work properly. As for the apps, I don't think you can launch apps from the command line as you would a shell command. You can try `/var/Applications/Name.app/Name` but I can't confirm if this works because my iPhone is not jailbroken.

Comment: I've seen that thread and tried both the commands you gave me, but they both just leave the console hanging and appear to do nothing. Thanks though.

Comment: @APShredder Maybe Apple disabled this "feature" or maybe the command was never updated for iOS 4. The link is from 2009 so it's possible that it just doesn't work. As for launching apps, it seems like you would need to launch them with SpringBoard but I don't know how you would do that.

Comment: OS X has the open command in the terminal, which uses the default system file handler to launch the file for example: `$ open /Applications/Safari.app/` will launch Safari. Not sure if it works on iOS, as I don't have a jailbroken phone. It can also open other things `$ open 'http://paperclipped.com/'` will open the the url in your default browser.

Comment: I appears that some of he commands aren't updated or something similar, which would explain why they don't work.